# Unexpected symbol: 'are' for if then else condition check

Tags: if-statement, github-actions

2 environment variables need to do a equally check before carry on the next sep in my workflow

```
  - name: version check
    env:
      version_in_code : "v$(poetry version -s)" 
      version_in_tag : $(git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h')) 
      version_is_equal: ${{ env.version_in_code != env.version_in_tag }}
    run: |
      if [ ${{ env.version_is_equal }} ]; #here comes the error
      then
      echo " ${{ env.version_in_tag }} will be released"
      else
      git push -d origin ${{ env.version_in_tag }}
      echo "⛔️ Tag-version: ${{ env.version_in_tag }} and Code-version: ${{ env.version_in_code are NOT equivalent"
      exit 1
      fi
```

Using `$env.version_is_equal` is not allowed inside the if condition check, and the error message is very confusing: `Unexpected symbol: 'are'` how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the syntax issue pointed out by Gui, but there is also a Bash problem: this

```bash
[ ${{ env.version_is_equal }} ]
```

is either `[ true ]` or `[ false ]`. This will always evaluate to `true`, because the construct checks if it contains a non-empty string; it doesn't care if the string is `true` or `false`.

Then, you can replace `${{ env.version_is_equal }}` with `$version_is_equal`; doesn't make much of a difference, but it's more convenient.

To fix the comparison, you either have to compare to a string:

```bash
if [ "$version_is_equal" = 'true' ]; then
```

or run it as a command (*without* the `[ ... ]`), which is shorter, but a bit more magic:

```bash
if "$version_is_equal"; then
```

This works because `true` and `false` are commands returning a success/failure exit status.

---

Notice that this

```yaml
      version_in_tag : $(git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h'))
```

is evaluated only when it is used, and not when it is assigned. Until it is used, it's just a string. This may or may not be the intention, but it's in my opinion more clear to make the assignment part of the script itself:

```bash
version_in_tag=$(git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an error in the syntax.

You didn't close the env variable on the error message implementation:

```
echo "⛔️ Tag-version: ${{ env.version_in_tag }} and Code-version: ${{ env.version_in_code are NOT equivalent"
```

You used `${{ env.version_in_code` instead of `${{ env.version_in_code }}`